# How do I create a JSON string from data stored in Google Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need my Google Firebase Database Data converted to a JSON string.

[image]

The desired outcome should be as follows:

```
var dataSet =[
{arr:"test",des:"DMM",eta:"17 Feb 2018 11:00",etd:"17 Feb 2018 13:30",gate:"S92", inbound:"RT456", org:"ARN", outbound:"RT678", remarks:"CHARTER", sta:"17 Feb 2018 11:00", std:"17 Feb 2018 13:30", whs:"T11"},
{arr:"test",des:"ESB",eta:"17 Feb 2018 09:00",etd:"17 Feb 2018 15:30",gate:"S94", inbound:"SD941", org:"JNB", outbound:"SD942", remarks:"", sta:"17 Feb 2018 09:00", std:"17 Feb 2018 15:30", whs:"T11"}
             ];
```

I'm new to this and have therefore no clue how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the DataSet-schedule object and then iterate for each of the objects inside it :

```
dbRef.child("DataSet-schedule").once("value").then(
    function(snapshot){
        var dataSetObj = snapshot.val(), text= "";
        for(x in dataSetObj){
            text += JSON.stringify(dataSetObj[x]);
            text+= "--";  //separator
        }
    var result = text.split("--");
    result.pop();
    }

);
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. I get an error on the first line `Uncaught ReferenceError: dbRef is not defined` I tried changing it into  `firebase.database().ref("DataSet-Schedule").once("value").then(` but then turns into another error message `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: JSON.Stringify is not a function`

Comment: @MK01111000  There's a slight typo in my code. The function's name is JSON.stringify() and not JSON.Stringify(). So, the code will work if you write **JSON.stringify(dataSetObj[x])**

Comment: Also after you do `result = text.split("--");`  make sure you pop the last element of the result array because it contains empty string.

So your code would look like
`var result = text.split("--");`
`result.pop();`

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

The JSON data is available at https://your-project.firebaseio.com/.json. You can obtain this by sending a `GET` request to this url. If you have classes in your data and would like to get the data for a particular class instead, use https://your-project.firebaseio.com/your-class.json

You can test this by using `curl https://your-project.firebaseio.com/.json`
For better readability you can use `curl https://your-project.firebaseio.com/.json?print=pretty`

Refer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data

Comment: @Anuuraag Baishya, thats very helpful indeed. Only thing is that I need the data without the push-keys, like in the "desired outcome" mentioned in my first post